# Prolog how to add element in a list if is in a list

Tags: prolog

I m trying to do a list member([member/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2)) with my own predicate.

starting this example

```
?-app([a,r,t],[t,s,m,n,a],L3). 

L3=[a,t]
```

I tried to do similar exercises so I did this with prolog:

```
app([],_,[]).
app([H|T],[H1,T1],[H|L1]):- H is H1,  L1 is H,! ,app(T,T1,L1).
app([_H|T],L,L2):-  app(T,L,L2).
```

and all working regular, but the value in a list will be overwritten during the execution, in fact, the trace is :

```
trace, app([3,2],[3,5],X).
   Call: (9) app([3, 2], [3, 5], _7426) ? creep
   Call: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Call: (10) _7736 is 3 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Call: (10) app([2], 5, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) app([], 5, 3) ? creep
   Fail: (11) app([], 5, 3) ? creep
   Fail: (10) app([2], 5, 3) ? creep
   Fail: (9) app([3, 2], [3, 5], _7426) ? creep
false.
```

I tried to make a modify on the base case in this way:

```
app([],_,_N).
```

but the output is every wrong:

```
trace, app([3,2],[3,5],X).
   Call: (9) app([3, 2], [3, 5], _7426) ? creep
   Call: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Call: (10) _7736 is 3 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3 is 3 ? creep
   Call: (10) app([2], 5, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) app([], 5, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (11) app([], 5, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (10) app([2], 5, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (9) app([3, 2], [3, 5], [3|3]) ? creep
X = [3|3].
```

where I m wrong?

Comment: In the example you've given, you wrote `[H1,T1]`, it's a list with only two elements. Are you sure about that?

Comment: member/2 does not use a list for the first argument. The first argument is an element. So either you need to change the question, or change your code.

Comment: @GuyCoder I think he is trying to implement similar function but with a list.

Comment: Just an aside, in your clause, `app([H|T],[H1,T1],[H|L1]):- H is H1,  L1 is H,! ,app(T,T1,L1).`, `is/2` is for arithmetic expression evaluation. Don't use it as some kind of assignment statement in Prolog. Prolog doesn't have an assignment operator. In this case, you  want *unification*, `=/2`. so `H = H1, L1 = H`. Actually, you can do the unification in the head of the predicate clause, so you could just write, `app([H|T],[H,T1],[H|H]):- !, app(T,T1,L1).` which is actually clearer as far as what the clause means, and a problem: `[H|H]`,

Comment: @LightYagami I get that, but remember that many inexperienced programmers come to this site and the confusion created by using the definition of member/2 with code that is not member/2 can be avoided if the OP just fixed the question.

Comment: You can't just change the type from element to list, you have to decide what semantics you're trying to achieve. It looks like you're trying to write set intersection, in which case you may want to [examine the prior art](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#intersection/3).

Comment: yes, you are right isn't a member/2, is an extension of member/2. With member/2 i wish find if element is in a given list. In my case i have 2 list, and i wish see if all element in a list one is in a list two. Is yes, put this number in a third list. @GuyCoder

Comment: @DanielLyons yes is the right. I don't think about this, but formally is an intersection between two lists! thanks for resource

Comment: I don't think to understand your point @lurker . I'm very basic on this language and i every thought that H is H1 is equivalent to H = H1 (in fact I use both of this operator in my code). I m new in this type of programming language and for me is very different to the other language

Comment: Nope. `H = H1` is completely different to `H is H1`. These operators are described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do a `sublist/2` predicate:

```
%! sublist(Sub, List)
% is true if Sub is a list that occurs in
% some position in List
sublist(Sub, List) :-
    % first partition off some tail of the list
    append(_Prefix, Tail, List),
    % then get some prefix of the tail, this is a sublist
    append(Sub, _TailTail, Tail).
```

There's more ways to do this, but I think `append/3` is simple to
understand. This is a different problem from `member/2`, which is finding elements in a list, here our problem is to carve up a list into chunks, hence the very different implementation than you see in `member/2`. You'll often find in Prolog the first step to a solution is to define the problem well. Good luck in your Prolog learning.